# Resources.resx error?

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error that reads:

The custom tool 'PublicResXFileCodeGenerator' failed while processing the file 'Properties\Resources.resx'

I haven't the slightest clue how to fix it. 
If any of you know what's going on here, I could use your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a .resx file is compiled, Visual Studio runs it through the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator (or InternalResXFileCodeGenerator, if it's visibility is internal) to generate the actual strongly-typed properties that you use in your code.

If there is something wrong with the XML in the file, malformed or corrupted perhaps, then the process might fail.  Can you open the file in the resource view?

Comment: Yes I can open it in the resources view.  What should I look for in here to correct any errors?

Comment: If it opens, then it's probably not corrupt, and it may be something else.  If you right click the file and say "View Code", the XML view will come up - just verify that all the key-value pairs look like `<data>` elements with a `<value>` child element.

Comment: Is there any way to safely reset the entire resources section?  I only have one image in my resources, and feel that it would be painless to just reset it and try again

Comment: You can delete the resource file and add a new one.  I hate to suggest it, but you might try restarting VS.  Every once in a while, it does get confused about things.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Copy the contents of Resources.resx to a new resource file.
2. Delete Resources.resx from the project.
3. Unload the project
4. Reload the project.

That should get rid of the compiler warning.

Comment: Instead of **Unloading** and **Reloading** you can **Right-click** on the `Resource.resx` file and click `Run Custom Tool`

Answer (score 0):

try this ..
Open your fileName.resx file in windows explorer and right click - Properties

maybe you will find "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer."

Check [Unblock] checkbox and apply then try to build your solution again.[image]